# Simultaneous congruence and Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

For example, if two given linear congruences have $m_1$ and $m_2$ not coprime, how to use CRT to show that there is no solution?

Should the solution start with assume there exists a solution then prove the contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Congruences also hold modulo any divisor of the modulus. Hence, given two linear congruences 
$$\begin{align*}
x\equiv a_1 \mod m_1 \\
x\equiv a_2 \mod m_2
\end{align*}$$
it is also true that
$$\begin{align*}
x\equiv a_1 \mod (m_1,m_2) \\
x\equiv a_2 \mod (m_1,m_2)
\end{align*}$$
It follows that, if $a_1\not\equiv a_2 \pmod{(m_1,m_2)}$, you have an obvious contradiction to the existence of any solution.

*Remark:* It is not difficult to prove that the converse holds, too. That is, if the above condition is satisfied, then there is a solution to this system.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are given

\begin{align}
   x &\equiv a_1 \mod{m_1} \\
   x &\equiv a_2 \mod{m_2}
\end{align}

Let $g = \gcd(m_1,m_2)$ and suppose

\begin{align}
   m_1 &= g \ n_1 \\
   m_2 &= g \ n_2
\end{align}

It follows that $a_1 \equiv a_2 \pmod g$

If this is true, then you can write

\begin{align}
   x &\equiv a_1 \mod{g} \\
   x &\equiv a_1 \mod{n_1} \\
   x &\equiv a_2 \mod{n_2}
\end{align}

where $n_1, n_2,$ and $g$ are all pairwise prime. So a solution can be found.

If $a_1 \not \equiv a_2 \pmod g$, then there is no solution.